# Sparse warnings: incorrect type in assignment

Tags: linux-kernel

I'm trying to make a patch but i never met this type of warning:

```
warning: incorrect type in assignment (different modifiers)
expected struct ipt_entry *[assigned] e
got struct ipt_entry [pure] *
```

This error appears at this point:

```
e = ipt_next_entry(e);
```

While the declaration of both e and ipt_next_entry looks like this:

```
struct ipt_entry *e;

static inline __pure
struct ipt_entry *ipt_next_entry(const struct ipt_entry *entry)
{
       return (void *)entry + entry->next_offset;
}
```

My question exactly: 
What __pure does? What can i do? Where can I read something about this? I really can't find anything on the internet.

Comment: Found this quickly enough: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/compiler-gcc.h#L94 it is a macro which expands to `__attribute__((pure))`, which you could have seen in the source code for yourself.  So... https://ohse.de/uwe/articles/gcc-attributes.html#func-pure

Answer (score 2):

From http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html

> **pure**
>
> return value depends only on the parameters and/or global variables.
>   Such a function can be subject to common subexpression elimination and
>   loop optimization just as an arithmetic operator would be. These
>   functions should be declared with the attribute pure. For example,
>             int square (int) **attribute** ((pure)); says that the hypothetical function square is safe to call fewer times than the
>   program says.
>
> Some of common examples of pure functions are strlen or memcmp.
>   Interesting non-pure functions are functions with infinite loops or
>   those depending on volatile memory or other system resource, that may
>   change between two consecutive calls (such as feof in a multithreading
>   environment).
>
> The attribute pure is not implemented in GCC versions earlier than
>   2.96.Many functions have no effects except the return value and their

Basically it is appended to functions which **read** global memory and do not modify anything. For eg, the `strlen()` function just reads the pointer and returns the length of the string, it doesn't modify the actual string.
On the other hand, `strcpy()` does modify the memory pointed to by one of the pointers.

> Such attributes (pure, const etc) help the compiler to know some semantic meaning of a
>   function call, so that it can apply higher optimization than to normal
>   functions.

Read more from this lwn article:  http://lwn.net/Articles/285332/

Comment: Glad could help! Read the `lwn` article, it explains these attributes really well.

Comment: Doing that right now. I understood what i have to do and what i have to modify. And why i should do this. thanks!